# Where is the merged Manifest in Flutter Project?

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, manifest

The merged Manifest window is not showing in Android Studio for Flutter Project. Where to find the merged manifest.

Comment: try opening standalone android project in studio

Answer (score 3):

You can find the merged manifests in the build folder.

```
<project>/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests directory
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used command line find to search for all files in the flutter project directory named AndroidManifest.xml.

```
find . -name "AndroidManifest.xml"
```

Since I was looking for a specific manifest relating to com.stripe.android.payments.StripeBrowserLauncherActivity, I then searched for all files containing the string StripeBrowserLauncherActivity in the build folder.

I found the manifest I was after in

```
build/app/intermediates/bundle_manifest/prodRelease/AndroidManifest.xml
```